# How to remove parts of the returned URL using getProductUrl within a rewrite?

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers

I was wondering if somebody might have a solution for me. Currently I have a working IndexController which brings back the correct sku from a search.

However the problem is that once the rewrite is made it adds the complete URL which does not link to a product page.

```
    // Check we have a product.
    if ($product->getId()) {
        // Get the URL and redirect to it.
        $url = $product->getProductUrl();
        if ($url) {
            $this->_redirectUrl('/support/'.$url);
            return true;
        }

    }
    // If we didn't find a matching product, load the default.
    $this->loadNoRoute();
    return false;
```

It then proceeds to load a URL like this: 
https://mywebiteurl/support/https://mywebsiteurl/macbook-pro.html

Where I require the URL to load like this:
https://mywebiteurl/support/macbook-pro.html

Wondering if anybody could point me in the right direction as I'm going round in circles. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get partial url ( without domain name ) using this code snipt :

```
$request = parse_url($url);
```

your code will be like this :

```
// Check we have a product.
if ($product->getId()) {
    // Get the URL and redirect to it.
    $url = $product->getProductUrl();

    // Parse URL
    $request = parse_url($url); 
    $pageUrl = $request['path']; // Get URL without domain name

    if ($url) {
        $this->_redirectUrl('/support/'.$pageUrl);
        return true;
    }

}
// If we didn't find a matching product, load the default.
$this->loadNoRoute();
return false;
```

hope it will help, or you can use that logic to implement your desired functionality.